AddRange/SaveChanges won't add data to database
My current task is to transform a huge tree-like structure to simple table (which i just created and it's empty) with each node having a parent Id and each node having an shared ancestor Id (if node has type_id and is present in another table, then this node is ancestor and each next node should have it's ID as Subdivision Id).
The tree-like structure is a company hierarchy structure, which is like 8 Mb and comes from REST service with function call
var root = await GetOrganizationStructureByBIN(unid);

First I want to show how this service and DbContext are configured:
Service:
services.AddTransient<IDirectoryService, DirectoryService>();

Setting up DbContext:
.AddDbContext<DbContextPostgreSql>(options =>
                options.UseNpgsql(mainDbConn ?? configuration.GetConnectionString("DbContextPostgreSql")));

DI DbContext in service:
private readonly DbContextPostgreSql _db;

public DirectoryService(DbContextPostgreSql db)
{
    _db = db;
}

I've written some stack code to traverse through the tree structure iteratively and everything seems to work pretty fine, but it doesn't add any data to the database.
public async Task UpdateDatabaseDepartmentsLinkedLotus(string unid)
{
    if (_db.Database.GetDbConnection().State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning("Database connection is not open. Reopening connection.");
        await _db.Database.OpenConnectionAsync();
    }

    List<OrganizationLinkedLotus> organizationsLinkedLotus;

    try
    {
        organizationsLinkedLotus = await GetOrganizationsLinkedLotus();
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception($"CAN'T GET ORGANIZATIONSLINKEDLOTUS ->{e.Message}");
    }

    _logger.LogInformation($"Total organizations: {organizationsLinkedLotus.Count}");

    foreach (var org in organizationsLinkedLotus)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Organization: {org.Name}, ID: {org.Id}");
    }

    var organizationsMap = new Dictionary<string, int>(organizationsLinkedLotus.Count);
    var processedDepartmentsList = new List<DepartmentLinkedLotus>();

    for (int i = 0; i < organizationsLinkedLotus.Count; i++)
    {
        var curr = organizationsLinkedLotus[i];
        organizationsMap[curr.Id] = i;
    }

    var root = await GetOrganizationStructureByBIN(unid);
    _logger.LogInformation($"organizationsMap as string -> -> -> {organizationsMap[root.UNID]}");
    var stack = new Stack<(OrganizationStructure Node, 
            string ParentId, string SubdivisionId, string TypeId)>();

    if (organizationsMap.ContainsKey(root.UNID))
    {
        var orgLinkedLotus = organizationsLinkedLotus[organizationsMap[root.UNID]];
        stack.Push((root, root.UNID, root.UNID, orgLinkedLotus.TypeId));
    } 
    else
    {
        stack.Push((root, root.UNID, "", ""));
    }

    _logger.LogInformation($"RIGHT BEFORE LOOP {stack.Count}");

    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var (currentNode, parentId, subdivisionId, typeId) = stack.Pop();

        _logger.LogInformation($"STARTED THE LOOP UNID{currentNode.UNID} {currentNode.Name.RU}");

        if (currentNode.UNID == null)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"COULD NOT GET UNID OF CURRENT NODE {currentNode.Name}");
            continue;
        }

        var departmentEntity = new DepartmentLinkedLotus()
            {
                DepartmentName = currentNode.Name.RU,
                Id = currentNode.UNID,
                ParentId = parentId,
                SubdivisionId = subdivisionId,
                TypeId = typeId
            };

        processedDepartmentsList.Add(departmentEntity);
        _logger.LogInformation($"Entities to save: {_db.ChangeTracker.Entries<DepartmentLinkedLotus>().Count(e => e.State == EntityState.Added)}");

        _db.DepartmentsLinkedLotus.Add( departmentEntity );

        string nextTypeId, nextSubdivisionId;

        if (organizationsMap.ContainsKey(currentNode.UNID))
        {
            var nextOrg = organizationsLinkedLotus[organizationsMap[currentNode.UNID]];

            nextTypeId = nextOrg.TypeId;
            nextSubdivisionId = nextOrg.Id;
        } 
        else
        {
            nextTypeId = typeId;
            nextSubdivisionId = subdivisionId;
        }

        if (currentNode.Department != null)
        {
            foreach(var child in currentNode.Department)
            {
                stack.Push((child, currentNode.UNID, subdivisionId, typeId));
            }
        }
    }

    _logger.LogInformation($"Processed Departments Count: {processedDepartmentsList.Count}");
    await SaveDepartmentsInBatches(processedDepartmentsList);
}

And this is function to save the data into the database in batches, I've tried both methods trying saving in batches and whole list at once
private async Task SaveDepartmentsInBatches(List<DepartmentLinkedLotus> departments, int batchSize = 100)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < departments.Count; i += batchSize)
    {
        var batch = departments.Skip(i).Take(batchSize).ToList();
        _logger.LogInformation($"current batch exemplair{batch[0].DepartmentName} = type_id {batch[0].TypeId}");
        _db.DepartmentsLinkedLotus.AddRange(batch);

        try
        {
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Error during SaveChangesAsync: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}

The strange thing logging always logs different things, sometimes like this:
2024-11-30 00:04:19.5048|4||||EmployeeHttpClient|INFO|organizationsMap as string -> -> -> 4
2024-11-30 00:04:19.5048|4||||EmployeeHttpClient|INFO|RIGHT BEFORE LOOP 1
2024-11-30 00:04:19.5048|4||||EmployeeHttpClient|INFO|STARTED THE LOOP UNIDA8925F4E89C9541A46257F070017B9F9 ОБЪЕДИНЕНИЕ ДИВИЗИОН СЕТЬ
2024-11-30 00:04:31.6551|10||||EmployeeHttpClient|INFO|EXECUTION STARTED UNID -> -> -> 940241000314
2024-11-30 00:04:31.6959|10||||EmployeeHttpClient|WARN|Database connection is not open. Reopening connection.
2024-11-30 00:04:31.6959|10||||IISHttpServer|ERROR|Connection ID "17365880173341179980", Request ID "8000004e-0002-f100-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.|System.InvalidOperationException: Can't close, connection is in state Connecting
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Close(Boolean async)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.CloseAsync()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<DisposeAsync>g__DisposeAsyncCore|109_0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.ResetStateAsync(Boolean disposeDbConnection)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.<DisposeAsync>g__Await|22_0(Int32 i, ValueTask vt, List`1 toDispose)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.DisposeAsync()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.<DisposeAsync>g__Await|22_0(Int32 i, ValueTask vt, List`1 toDispose)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.RequestServicesFeature.<DisposeAsync>g__Awaited|9_0(RequestServicesFeature servicesFeature, ValueTask vt)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.FireOnCompleted()|[Void Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine ByRef)] => [Void MoveNext()] => [Void ApplicationError(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger, System.String, System.String, System.Exception)]

Sometimes it logged that DbContext has already been disposed or something like that. And sometimes it won't even log any error, it goes all seemingly well and returns status 200, but data is not added to the table and it's still empty.

DbContext registered as Scoped, DirectoryService as Transient. That means that every new DirectoryService, will have the same DbContext within scope. How do you use DirectoryService? Who instantiated it? If it is background task there should be right dependency resolving.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Yeah, DirectoryService was written before me and it is mostly used to read data from static JSON files located inside server catalogue. But i've copied same function in other service which is registered as Scoped and this didn't work anyway...
